# How to address JNDI configuration when using mvn scala:console

Tags: maven-2, scala, scala-2.8, lift

I'm troubleshooting a Mapper problem and I'm running into an issue trying to use a Mapper class inside of the Scala/Lift console. Our MetaMappers have their datasource configured through a ConnectionIdentifier that points to a JDBC datasource configured in JNDI.  This works great when bootstrapping through Jetty.

When loading the console and running `(new bootstrap.liftweb.Boot).boot` to initialize, `Schemifier.schemify` fails JNDI configuration is not available.

```
scala> (new bootstrap.liftweb.Boot).boot
java.lang.NullPointerException: Looking for Connection Identifier ConnectionIdentifier(jdbc/svcHub) but failed to find either a JNDI data source with the name jdbc/svcHub or a lift connection manager with the correct name
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DB.scala:141)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DB.scala:141)
    at net.liftweb.common.EmptyBox.openOr(Box.scala:465)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$$anonfun$7.apply(DB.scala:140)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$$anonfun$7.apply(DB.scala:140)
    at net.liftweb.common.EmptyBox.openOr(Box.scala:465)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$.newConnection(DB.scala:134)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$.getConnection(DB.scala:230)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.DB$.use(DB.scala:581)
    at net.liftweb.mapper.Schemifier$.schemify(Sche...
```

Essentially, I'd like to have full MetaMapper functionality from within the console. My question is: What's the best way to bootstrap a Lift app from the console such that the JNDI-based dependencies can also be fulfilled outside of a JNDI-capable web container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a application server it's likely that the server will provide a JNDI context for you. In a standalone application you must provide a JNDI Context your self. For that you can use a [javax.naming.InitialContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html).

There is a nice example using Apache's DBCP here: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/guide/jndi-howto.html. Of course, will you have to fix the Datasource objects to the implementation you are using.

This will be enough (not very elegant, though) for simple JNDI usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm really looking, though, for a way that I can swap in a different JNDI provider without modifying the source code of the application.